# partial view coming without validation attributes (ASP.NET MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation, asp.net-mvc-templates

A weird thing keeps happening on one of my ASP.NET MVC 3 apps.

I am fetching insert rows via jQuery Ajax api and there is no problem with that. But when I get the necessary partial view back, it is coming without validation attributes and I am unable to rebind the validation for those rows.

Here is what I get as ajax response:

```
<input type="hidden" name="accommPropertyPeriods.index" autocomplete="off" value="ccaa15b3-76f1-4215-8bb5-a62d700bfc1e" />
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <select class="chzn-select-deselect" data-placeholder="Choose an Alias..." id="accommPropertyPeriods_ccaa15b3-76f1-4215-8bb5-a62d700bfc1e__AccommPropertySeasonPeriodAliasID" name="accommPropertyPeriods[ccaa15b3-76f1-4215-8bb5-a62d700bfc1e].AccommPropertySeasonPeriodAliasID" style="min-width:100px;"><option value="302">A</option>
<option value="303">B</option>
<option value="304">C</option>
<option value="305">D</option>
</select>

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="datefield" id="accommPropertyPeriods_ccaa15b3-76f1-4215-8bb5-a62d700bfc1e__PeriodStartsAt" name="accommPropertyPeriods[ccaa15b3-76f1-4215-8bb5-a62d700bfc1e].PeriodStartsAt" type="text" value="" />

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="datefield" id="accommPropertyPeriods_ccaa15b3-76f1-4215-8bb5-a62d700bfc1e__PeriodEndsAt" name="accommPropertyPeriods[ccaa15b3-76f1-4215-8bb5-a62d700bfc1e].PeriodEndsAt" type="text" value="" />

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    </table>
```

Here is what I should be getting :

```
<input type="hidden" name="accommPropertyPeriods.index" autocomplete="off" value="84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d" />
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <select class="chzn-select-deselect" data-placeholder="Choose an Alias..." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AccommPropertySeasonPeriodAliasID must be a number." data-val-required="The AccommPropertySeasonPeriodAliasID field is required." id="accommPropertyPeriods_84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d__AccommPropertySeasonPeriodAliasID" name="accommPropertyPeriods[84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d].AccommPropertySeasonPeriodAliasID" style="min-width:100px;"><option value="302">A</option>
<option value="303">B</option>
<option value="304">C</option>
<option value="305">D</option>
</select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="accommPropertyPeriods[84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d].AccommPropertySeasonPeriodAliasID" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="datefield" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PeriodStartsAt field is required." id="accommPropertyPeriods_84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d__PeriodStartsAt" name="accommPropertyPeriods[84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d].PeriodStartsAt" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="accommPropertyPeriods[84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d].PeriodEndsAt" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="datefield" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PeriodEndsAt field is required." id="accommPropertyPeriods_84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d__PeriodEndsAt" name="accommPropertyPeriods[84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d].PeriodEndsAt" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="accommPropertyPeriods[84ddd0f5-a3e2-4f10-8e67-f32528c6393d].PeriodEndsAt" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    </table>
```

> GUIDs don't have to be the same. I am doing so-called non-sequential binding.

Here is the the action which I am invoking through jquery ajax to get a new insert row:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult accommPropertySeasonPeriodCreatePartialView(int id, int subid) {

        //some other stuff going on here. non-related to partial view.

        return PartialView("_AccommPropertySeasonPeriodCreatePartialView");
    }
```

I am nearly out of my mind to figure out why this is happening. Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Html.*` helpers such as `Html.TextBoxFor`, `Html.CheckBoxFor`, ... emit validation attributes only if used inside a form. So make sure you wrap them in a `Html.BeginForm` call. As far as client side validation is concerned, you should call the [`jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse`](http://itmeze.com/2010/10/08/client-side-validation-after-ajax-partial-view-result-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) method after you update your DOM in order to reapply client validation. And [yet another article](http://codercolumn.com/mvc-3-ajax-dialogs).

If you don't have a form you can cheat and put the following in the partial:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

Now the helper will emit data-* validation attributes on the input field.

Comment: oww, it is going to be a problem. I already have a form on my primary view. Any other way to get around with this automatically or should I override the Editor templates?

Comment: @tugberk, see my update about manually instantiating the FormContext in the partial.

Comment: Awesome! Totally worked. Just to understand it, what exactly this tweak tells the framework (or the templating engine?) so that it understands to emit data-* validation attributes on the input field?

Comment: @tugberk, this tells the helpers that they are inside a form :-) Basically inside all html helpers there is a test whether the current  ViewContext.FormContext property is null. And they generate data-* attributes only if it is not null. When you use a form this is automatically instantiated but when you don't have a form it is null.

Comment: So cool! I am gonna totally blog about it and steal your sentence :) (by giving you the credit of course) It looks like a hack but you made it sound like a legitimate stuff. Is it?